# How to increase speed while maintaining memory with numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to write a code to do a one-sample t-test given the sample mean (E(X)) and sample second raw moment (E(X^2)) for each entry in a 2-dimensional array.

There are two ways I am doing this but both of them are not quite working.

1. With numpy vetorized operations - out of memory error for certain sizes of the array.

```py
def calc_normal_pvals(vt_sum_counter, vt_ssum_counter):
    global nsubs
    vt_sum_counter = vt_sum_counter/nsubs
    vt_ssum_counter = vt_ssum_counter/nsubs
    sample_var = nsubs * (vt_ssum_counter - np.square(vt_sum_counter))/(nsubs - 1)
    t_array = np.divide(vt_sum_counter, (np.sqrt(sample_var/nsubs)))
    pvals = t.sf(t_array, nsubs-1)
    pvals[np.isnan(pvals)] = 0
    return pvals
```

2. Normal for loop method - takes a lot of time in comparison

```py
def calc_normal_pvals(vt_sum_counter, vt_ssum_counter, tail=1):
    global nsubs
    V, T = vt_sum_counter.shape
    pvals = np.zeros((V, T))
    for i in range(V):
        for j in range(T):
            sigma = ((vt_ssum_counter[i, j]/nsubs -(vt_sum_counter[i,j]/nsubs)**2)/(nsubs - 1))**0.5
            if (sigma != 0):
                pvals[i, j] = t.sf(vt_sum_counter[i, j]/(nsubs*sigma), nsubs-1)
    return pvals
```

The input arrays are huge - typically of size ~ 900000 X 400.

Comment: What line throws the memory error?

Comment: It changes with systems. But the best it went was the line "pvals = t.sf(t_array, nsubs -1)".

Comment: The gist of the question is how can I write such a code more efficiently.

Comment: Can you combine the two, working with chunks.  For example a 100 iterations on 9000 x 400 arrays.  Due to memory management issues, a few iterations on a complex operation are often optimal.

Comment: @hpaulj, yeah I was thinking of the same. I wanted to know if there is a cool numpy trick.